# MySQL refuses to use index for UPDATE query with SELECT in SET clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-performance

I need to fill the `location` field in `users` table with a country name from `geoip` table, depending on the user's IP.

Here is the tables' CREATE code.

```
CREATE TABLE `geoip` (
    `IP_FROM` INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
    `IP_TO` INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
    `COUNTRY_NAME` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`IP_FROM`, `IP_TO`)
)    
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' 
    `password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    `ip` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT ''
    `location` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT ''
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `login` (`login`), 
    INDEX `ip` (`ip`(10))   
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

The update query I try to run is:

```
UPDATE users u
SET u.location = 
(SELECT COUNTRY_NAME FROM geoip WHERE INET_ATON(u.ip) BETWEEN IP_FROM AND IP_TO)
```

The problem is that this query refuses to use `PRIMARY` index on the `geoip` table, though it would speed things up a lot. The EXPLAIN gives me:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             u       index   NULL            PRIMARY 4       NULL        1254395 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  geoip   ALL     PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    62271       Using where
```

I've ended up converting `geoip` table to the MEMORY engine for this query only, but I'd like to know what was the right way to do it.

**UPDATE**
The DBMS I'm using is MariaDB 10.0.17, if it could make a difference.

Comment: probably the inet_aton() is throwing things off. you're forcing the DB to convert all of your IPs on the fly, so it's impossible to use an index - the derived value is unindexed.

Comment: @MarcB, unfortunately, the query plan stays the same even if I create an INT column with calculated INET_ATON() result and run the query using this column.

Comment: It is not the inet_aton - that was my first thought too but the index is on the ip_from and ip_to columns and it will be used fine on select with range optimization. As far as I remember NULL columns might be ignored in query optimization so this is my current theory.

Comment: I've checked, NULL is also not a case here. Even if I use INT NOT NULL column, it still ignores index. Also, index is being used if I use some integer constant instead of the actual `ip` column. So, maybe a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to force the index like this

```
UPDATE users u
SET u.location = 
(SELECT COUNTRY_NAME FROM geoip FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) 
 WHERE INET_ATON(u.ip) BETWEEN IP_FROM AND IP_TO)
```

Also since ip can be NULL it probably messing with index optimiziation.

Comment: That's right, I wanted MySQL to use PRIMARY index on `geoip`, so the country lookup could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The IP ranges are non-overlapping, correct?  You are not getting any IPv6 addresses?  (The world ran out of IPv4 a couple of years ago.)

No, the index won't be used, or at least won't perform as well as you would like.  So, I have devised a scheme to solve that.  However it requires reformulating the schema and building a Stored Routine.  [See my IP-ranges blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges);  It has links to code for IPv4 and for IPv6.  It will usually touch only one row in the table, not have to scan half the table.

**Edit**

MySQL does not know that there is only one range (from/to) that should match.  So, it scans far too much.  The difference between the two encodings of IP (INT UNSIGNED vs VARCHAR) makes it difficult to use a JOIN (instead of a subquery).  Alas a JOIN would not be any better because it does not understand that there is exactly one match.  Give this a try:

```
UPDATE  users u
    SET u.location = 
      ( SELECT  COUNTRY_NAME
            FROM  geoip
            WHERE  INET_ATON(u.ip) BETWEEN IP_FROM AND IP_TO
            LIMIT  1   -- added
      )
```

If that fails to significantly improve the speed, then change from `VARCHAR` to `INT UNSIGNED` in `users` and try again (without `INET_ATON`).

Comment: This is getting a little off-topic. What you offer requires some additional changes being done, though in my case I was better off converting the `geoip` table to MEMORY engine and getting the task done in some 5 minutes. What I wanted to know is why MySQL refused to use index in subquery as it would do for 

    `SELECT COUNTRY_NAME FROM geoip WHERE INET_ATON('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') BETWEEN IP_FROM AND IP_TO`